# Cakephp 4 Slug Generation

Tags: php, cakephp, content-management-system, slug, cakephp-4.x

I have a problem. I'm building a CMS in Cakephp based on the guide on their official website. Everything is going well but I have a problem.
As the article adds, no service is generated.
Everything is 100% done as per the tutorial.

Can you guess what it is caused by?

I put this in ArticlesTable, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\Utility\Text;
use Cake\Event\EventInterface;

class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options)
    {
        if ($entity->isNew() && !$entity->slug) {
            $sluggedTitle = Text::slug($entity->title);
            $entity->slug = substr($sluggedTitle, 0, 191);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('articles');
        $this->setDisplayField('title');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Editions', [
            'foreignKey' => 'edition_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Categories', [
            'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('ArticlesComments', [
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('ArticlesGalleries', [
            'foreignKey' => 'article_id',
        ]);

    }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You create slug at wrong place. Read https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#Cake\ORM\Entity::set

Comment: @Salines There's nothing wrong with creating slugs in the `beforeSave` handler, unless you want to validate them using application rules, as they are applied before the event is being triggered.

Comment: Usually, one would use behaviors for this, https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/docs/Behavior/Slugged.md for example. Those help to keep this reoccurring logic out of the main app code, it also is a bit more complicated than just using Text::slug() as you need to account for uniqueness and alike.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are adding it to ArticlesTable.php (src/Model/Table/ArticlesTable.php
2. Make sure you have added the following use statements:

```php
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Utility\Text;
use Cake\Event\EventInterface;
```

I could only get it to work having them in this exact order, if the ordering of the use statements is different mine do not generate slugs.

Full code:

```php
<?php
// src/Model/Table/ArticlesTable.php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Utility\Text;
use Cake\Event\EventInterface;

class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp'); // automatically adds created and modified columns
    }

    public function beforeSave(EventInterface $event, $entity, $options)
    {
        if($entity->isNew() && !$entity->slug)
        {
            $sluggedTitle = Text::slug($entity->title);
            //trim slug to max. length
            $entity->slug = substr($sluggedTitle, 0, 191);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

This is specific to Page 56 of the CakePHPCookbook (Nov. 24 2023 release) 5.x, therefore it may not be accurate later on.